# Does the concept of enlightenment apply to sects which only believe in Bhakti?

Tags: bhakti, enlightenment

Enlightenment as applied to enlightened being such as Ramana Maharishi implies a radical change of consciousness from the everyday state.

Does that apply to followers of sects that only believe in Bhakti?

Comment: This question has huge implications. :)

Comment: This question is too vague as it stands. For instance, what constitutes a radical change? How do one derive a working definition of Enlightenment from "Enlightenment as applied to enlightened being such as Ramana Maharishi"? What is everyday state of consciousness? Is it the same for everyone or does it vary from person to person? If yes, how is it characterised? If no, how is it characterised?

Comment: On the contrary, enlightenment is a function of gnyana. Bhakti is a means to gnyaya. It also serves to fill one's life with rasa.

Comment: As far as I can see Bhakti always relates to dAsatva or slavery or servitude and which is as opposed to Mukti or liberation as anything.

Comment: All the questions raised by lakshminarayana are intuitively understood and "common definition s" are accepted by normal human beings I.e. those like us as opposed to Ramana . further refinement can be given in answers.OP is fine as is.

Answer (score 2):

Bhakti is one of the ways in developing an inclination towards the God, whereas the REALISATION stage of the sages like Sri Ramana Maharshi is the final stage.

Many saints, who started in Bhakti marga, finally ended in SELF REALISATION.  [Yogi Ramaiah](http://www.arunachala-ramana.org/forum/index.php?topic=5288.0), [Saint Namadev](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Namdev), etc, are a few such people quoted for illustration purpose.

Saint Namadev was a devotee of Vitthal, Sri Krishna.  Later he got REALISATION.

> Once all Saints had assembled. Muktabai asked Gora Kumbhar to test all
>   the assembled Saints. He picked up a piece of wood and slowly tapped
>   it on the head of all Saints. When he tapped it on the head of Namdev,
>   Namdev did not say anything, but anger could be seen on his face. His
>   ego was hurt and he thought, 'How can I be tested like an earthen pot
>   ?' Later Gora Kumbhar said, "Except Namdev all other earthen pots are
>   well baked". After listening to this, Namdev went to Vithhal and told
>   Him what had happened. God told him, "When Muktabai and Goroba are
>   saying your head is not developed then it must be true, because you
>   have not taken the shelter of Sadguru. There is this devotee of mine,
>   Visoba Khechar, you go and meet him. He will bestow you with
>   knowledge".
>
> When Namdev came to see Visoba Khechar, Visoba was sleeping with his
>   feet resting on a Shiva pindi (shivaling). Namdev was outraged and
>   asked him to move his feet away from the Shivaling. Visoba told
>   Namdev, "You place my feet in a place where Shiva does not exists".
>   Wherever Namdev would put Visoba's feet, a Shivalinga would manifest
>   there. The entire sanctum sanctorum was filled with Shivalingas.
>   Namdev was perplexed to see this. Visoba Khechar then explained to
>   Namdev, "God is everywhere; but our sensory organs do not realise
>   that". After hearing this, Namdev was filled with devotion. With the
>   grace of Guru he received the knowledge that '***Brahma is everywhere***'.
>   Blockquote

—[Pujya Dr. Vasant Balaji Athavale, Hinduism for Kids (1990)](https://www.hindujagruti.org/hinduism-for-kids/629.html)